# How to prevent the calling of the willTerminate method?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, background

I'm developing an iOS application to keep track of certain system information from the device. The application is supposed to keep sending information even if it is in background. Everything is working fine but when I shut down the device and then turn it on, the application is still in background but it won't communicate the information (this because the willTerminate method was called at the shut down process). Can someone help me to prevent the calling of the willTerminate method?

Comment: Comment it out, perhaps?

Comment: What will preventing it do?  If the system wants to terminate the app, the willTerminate delegate call is a courtesy to your app.  There is no way that your app can block a terminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **applicationWillTerminate**: method in the **AppDelegate** is just an receiver of a particular notification. applicationWillTerminate get called just before to exit. You can not control anything but to save things important, because app is going to exit..

*The method is there for you only to know the app is going to exit.*

Comment: Thank you, I will restructure my question